# How to figure out the limit of this question

Tags: integration, statistics, inequality

I am  trying to solve this question:

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with joint density
>   $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array} {cc} 
>    2 &\text{ for } 0<x<y<1   \\
>    0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{array} \right.  $$
>   Find the density function of $Z$ where $Z=X+Y$.

The given solution is:

> if $Z=X+Y$ then (from a given theorem earlier), $$f_Z(z)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(u,z-u) \,\mathrm{d}x \tag{1}$$ .
>
> Consider the support of $f_{X,Y}$ that is, $\{(x,y):0<x<y<1\}$. In order for the integrand in (1) to take non-zero values we need $0<u<z-u<1$. This implies:
>
> $$\begin{array} {cc} 0<u<\frac{z}{2} & \text{ if } 0<z<1 \\
> z-1<u<\frac{z}{2} & \text{ if } 1<z<2 \tag{2}\\
> \end{array}$$
>   Thus the marginal density for the sum if:
>   $$ f_Z(z) = \left\{ \begin{array} {cc} 
>    \int\limits_0^\frac{z}{2} 2 \, \mathrm{d}u=z & 0<z<1   \\
>    \int\limits_{z-1}^\frac{z}{2} 2 \, \mathrm{d}u= 2-z & 1<z<2 \\
>     0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{array} \right.  $$

There two points I need help on:

**Question 1**

I can understand why we need $0<u<z-u<1$. However, it is not clear to me why this must imply we must divide the integrand into two regions, namely $0<z<1$ and $1<z<2$ and not some other region. In fact, it did not occur to me that I must split the integrand at all. Please help me see why I must perform the integrand in the way it is described in the solution.

**Question 2**
Having looked at the solution, I tried to redo the question (just accepted that I need to split the integration into two) and tried to obtain the inequalities in (2) but was not successful in getting the second inequality i.e. $z-1<u<\frac{z}{2}$. Instead I got the following:

$$\begin{array}  {cc} 0<z<2 & \Rightarrow& 1<x+y<2 \\
& \Rightarrow & 0<z-1<1 \\ 
& \Rightarrow & 0<u+y-1<u<1 \\
& \Rightarrow & 0<x+y-1<y<1 \\
& \Rightarrow & 0<z-1<u<1 \\
& \Rightarrow & z-1 <u<1
\end{array} $$

Did I make and error somewhere? I know this can't be the answer because then $f_Z(z)$ won't integrate to $1$ from $0<z<2$. But I am not able to find my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall not redo the computations here, but explain "why we must divide the integrand into two regions".

Given the joint density of $f_{(X,Y)}$ the cumulative distribution function $F_Z$ of the random variable $Z:=X+Y$ is given by
$$F_Z(z):=P[X+Y\leq z]=2\>{\rm area}(B_z)\ ,\tag{1}$$
where $$B_z:=\bigl\{(x,y)\>|\>0\leq x\leq y, \ x+y\leq z\bigr\}\ .$$
The factor $2$ in the formla $(1)$ comes from $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=2$ in the large triangle, which takes care of the fact that the area of this triangle is ${1\over2}$.

[image]

Looking at the above figure we have to realize that ${\rm area}(B_z)$ is not given by a single universal expression in the variable $z$, and that it will be necessary to distinguish cases, the most important one being $z\leq1$ vs. $z\geq1$. Having done the geometry properly it is then an easy matter to compute
$$f_Z(z)={d\over dz}F_Z(z)\ ,$$
and you will obtain the values given in the book.

Comment: did you mean to provide a figure to for $B_z$ ? I  am not sure where the $2$ in the $2\>{\rm area}(B_z)$ come from. Based on the definition of $B_z$, I thought $F_Z(z)$ would be $F_Z(z):=P[X+Y\leq z]={\rm area}(B_z)$

Answer (score 5):

**Question 1:** You don't have to do it this way. The reason for the splitting is the following: If $z \in (0,1)$, then the condition $z-u<1$ is automatically satisfied, so $$0 < u < z-u < 1 \iff 0<u < u-z.$$ In contrast, for $z \in [1,2)$, we really have to ensure that $z-u<1$, i.e. there is some extra condition.

**Question 2:** How do you get from $0<z-1<1$ to $0<u+y-1<u<1$....?

Do it step by step: Fix $u \in (0,1)$.

1. If $z \in (0,1)$, then $z-u<1$ is trivially satisfied (as $u>0$). Consequently, $$u < z-u < 1 \iff u<z-u.$$ The right-hand side is equivalent to $2u<z$, i.e. $u< \frac{z}{2}$.
2. Let $z \in (1,2)$. We can split $u<z-u<1$ into two (separate) conditions:

   - $u<z-u$: As in the first case, this is equivalent to $u< \frac{z}{2}$.
   - $z-u<1$: This inequality is equivalent to $1+u > z$, i.e. satisfied if $u>z-1$.

   Consequently, $u<z-u<1$ holds if, and only if, $$z-1<u< \frac{z}{2}.$$

**Geometric interpretation:**
[image]

- The condition $u<z-u$ corresponds to $u \in (0,1)$ such that the function colored in orange (namely, $f(u)=u$) is below the function colored in green ($f(u)=z-u$).
- The condition $z-u<1$ corresponds to $u \in (0,1)$ such that the function colored in green is below the black dotted line.
- The points $u \in (0,1)$ satisfying both constraints are colored in red.

For $z \in (0,1]$ we see that the second condition is always satisfied (the green line is always below the dotted line) whereas for $z >1$ this is not true anymore.

Comment: It is possible to explain this using graphs and geometry?

Comment: @mauna See my edited answer.